# SharePoint file updates reminder/push notification questions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, notifications

I have an Excel sheet (worklog) in my SharePoint folder, I wonder if it is possible to have a feature that:

- Send a push notification/or reminder to remind the people having access to the Excel sheet to do data entry at the end of each business day.
- When changes are made to the Excel sheet by a person (e.g named A), the admin/or defined managing user group will receive a push notification telling that A has updated the file.

As long as those 2 needs can be achieved, I don't mind if the solutions require external services or coding work. It would be great if the community can give me hint/map to follow for such requirements.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can build a [scheduled cloud flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks) like below to remind your users. Fill the "To" section under Send an email notification(V3) action with the emails of the users having access to the Excel sheet.
   [image]
   [image]
2. You can build an automated cloud flow like below. Fill the "To" section under Send an email notification(V3) action with the email of admin/or defined managing user group.
   [image]